# Add a new line after a regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to add a new line every time my program finds a regex. I want to keep the regex and only have a new line begin after it. The text is read from a `.txt` file.
I am able to find the regex, but when I try to add a new line, it returns as shown below, in **Actual output**.
I have been trying to fix this for hours, and would be glad about help.

Here is a quick example:

**In:**

```
STLB 1234 444 text text text
STLB 8796 567 text text text
```

**EDIT In:**

```
STLB 1234 444text text text

STLB 8796 567text text text
```

**Wanted Output:**

```
STLB 1234 444
text text text
STLB 8796 567
text text text
```

**Actual Output:**

```
(STLB.*\d\d\d) 

(STLB.*\d\d\d)
```

**Here is my code:**

```
stlb_match = re.compile('|'.join(['STLB.*\d\d\d']))

with open(in_file5, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fin5, open(out_file5, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout5:
    lines = fin5.read().splitlines()

    for i, line in enumerate(lines):
        matchObj1 = re.match(start_rx, line)

        if not matchObj1:
            first_two_word = (" ".join(line.split()[:2]))

            if re.match(stlb_match,line):
                line =re.sub(r'(STLB.*\d\d\d)', r'(STLB.*\d\d\d)'+' \n', line)
            elif re.match(first_two_word, line):
                line = line.replace(first_two_word, "\n" + first_two_word)

        fout5.write(line)
```

Comment: .* after STLB is dangerous. Instead use \s  ..some thing like this (STLB\s\d*) OR (STLB \d*)

Comment: You need to change this line `line =re.sub(r'(STLB.*\d\d\d)', r'(STLB.*\d\d\d)'+' \n` to `line =re.sub(r'(STLB.*\d\d\d)', r'\1\n` When replacing what got captured, you need to use `\1`

Comment: `line = re.sub(r"(STLB.*\d\d\d).*", r"\1", line) +'\n'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your replacement part is wrong, youcannot put regex in it. Change to:

```
line = 'STLB 1234 444 text text text'
line = re.sub(r'(STLB.*\d\d\d)', r"\1\n", line)
print line
```

**Output:**

```
STLB 1234 444
 text text text
```

Or:

```
line = re.sub(r'(STLB.*\d\d\d) ', r"\1\n", line)
```

if you want to remove the space at the beginning of the second line

Comment: `.*` could be too greedy, e.g. if there are numbers inside `text text text`

Comment: @EricDuminil: You're right, but using `.*?` will insert the linefeed after the first 3 digits (i.e. between `123` and `4`) I'm using the OP's regex.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming the lines have always this format `STLB <number> <number> <text>`, this whould work:

### Code

```
with open(in_file5, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fin5, open(out_file5, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout5:
    for l in fin5:
      l = re.sub(r'(STLB\s*\d+\s*\d+)\s*', r'\1\n', l)

      fout5.write(l)
      fout5.write('\n')
```

### Input

```
STLB 1234 444 text text text
STLB 8796 567 text text text
```

### Output

```
STLB 1234 444
text text text

STLB 8796 567
text text text
```

Note the `\s*` at the end of the RegEx, but the capturing group ends before so, those trailing spaces are left out.

#### Using **list comprehension** and `writelines`

```
with open(in_file5, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as fin5, open(out_file5, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fout5:
    fout5.writelines([re.sub(r'(STLB\s*\d+\s*\d+)\s*', r'\1\n', l) for l in fin5])
```

Let me know if this works for you

Comment: @Mady please, if my answer worked for you, remember to mark it as accepted (green checkmark). Thnx in advance!